# Customize ClearableFileInput in django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I've got a form with `profile_picture=ImageField` field set to the initial value. It's using `ClearableFileInput` widget. I need to customize the form in the template, so I can't simply use `{{ form.profile_picture}}`. How can I split field elements and obtain something which looks like this:

```
{{ with picture=form.profile_picture }}
{{ picture.label_tag }}
<a href="{{ picture.url }}">
  <img src="{{ picture.url }}">
</a>
{{ picture.clear-picture }}
```

where `{{ picture.clear-picture }}` should generate checkbox to delete the old picture

Answer (score 8):

[@vadimchin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625592/7311767) is correct, but it requires a little modification for new versions of Django (2.0 onwards), since the [`ClearableFileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.ClearableFileInput) class has changed.

You have to override the `template_name` attribute of `ClearableFileInput`, by creating another template in your templates directory. For example:

```
class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = 'widgets/customclearablefileinput.html'
```

And fill customclearablefileinput.html with the desired code, modifying [the original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) of the template as you need.

You also have to make changes in your settings.py file, so Django lets you [override widget templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates) from your projects template directory: Add `'django.forms'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, and then add this code:

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override `ClearableFileInput`

```
class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    template_with_initial = (
        '%(initial_text)s: <a href="%(initial_url)s">%(initial)s</a> '
        '%(clear_template)s<br />%(input_text)s: %(input)s'
    )

    template_with_clear = '%(clear)s <label for="%(clear_checkbox_id)s">%(clear_checkbox_label)s</label>'
```

look at `render` method,

and after override, set

```
  class ExForm(forms.Form):
       image = ImageField(widget=CustomClearableFileInput)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (on base of @vadimchin's answer) and easier for me is overriding the parameter `template_name` in the `class ClearableFileInput`.

You only need to create a new class in forms.py

```py
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput

class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
  template_name = "your_path/custom_clearable_file_input.html"

field = forms.FileField(label = ... widget=CustomClearableFileInput(attrs={'placeholder': ...}))
```

And in the custom_clearable_file_input.html you can put [the django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) and customize it as you want.