# Cannot override templates found in admin/auth and admin/widgets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

#### Context

I want to override the following django templates:

- `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html`
- `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/change_password.html`

With these custom templates:

- `<project_root>/templates/admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html`
- `<project_root>/templates/admin/auth/user/change_password.html`

My `TEMPLATES` settings are configured as followed:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

#### Problem

While I have managed to successfully override a lot of other templates that exist in the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/` path, I cannot seem to be able to override templates that exist in the paths mentioned above.

Regarding the widgets, I also tried the instructions found in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/renderers/#templatessetting) and also adding `FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'` to no avail.

Comment: Have you seen these : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901700/6143954](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52901700/6143954)?

Comment: Yes, it did not help

Comment: See: [Templates which may be overridden per app or model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model).

Comment: Yeah, this does not really help either. All it says is about templates that can only be overriden globally and not per model/app. I was not trying to override the templates I mentioned per model/app anyway, I wanted to override them globally